# VMWare Server flakiness on Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-server, ubuntu-9.10

*Note: I looked into ESXi, but it does not support my CPU.*

I have encountered the following error on two machines:

1. Ubuntu Desktop 9.10 32-bit version, hardware is a 64-bit AMD AthlonX2 CPU and 1 GB RAM
2. Ubuntu Server 9.10 64-bit version, hardware is a 64-bit AMD Phenom CPU and 3 GB RAM

I started at the [Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Server), which led to this [blog post](http://radu.cotescu.com/2009/10/30/how-to-install-vmware-server-2-0-x-on-ubuntu-9-10-karmic-koala/) with an installer shell script that applied VMWare's patches for the 2.6.31-14-server kernel.

After a couple hiccups, I got things installed and was able to sign into the web admin on port 8333.

Attempting to stop VMWare using

> sudo /etc/init.d/vmware stop

saw a failure on the Virtual Network. Attempting to start it:

> sudo /etc/init.d/vmware start VMware
>   Server is installed, but it has not
>   been (correctly) configured for the
>   running kernel. To (re-)configure it,
>   invoke the following command:
>   /usr/bin/vmware-config.pl.

Running the configuration says:

> sudo /usr/bin/vmware-config.pl  The
>   following VMware kernel modules have
>   been found on your system that were 
>   not installed by the VMware Installer.
>   Please remove them then run this 
>   installer again.
>
> vmmon vmci vmnet
>
> I.e. - 'rm
>   /lib/modules/2.6.31-14-server/misc/.{o,ko}'
>
> Execution aborted.

Following these instructions sometimes gives a working system, sometimes it take a couple tries. The server will work for a little bit, then throw the same error.

Has anyone got a stable VMWare Server setup on a Ubuntu Server 9.10 host? If so, how?

Comment: No real solution, we ended up rolling back to an older kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why you must run Ubuntu 9.10 as the VMWare Server host OS?

I have been reliably running VMWare Server (1 & 2) with Ubuntu Server 8.04LTS for years.

It is supported by VMWare and installation is a lot simpler.
i.e. Install gcc and your kernel headers and you are good to go.

I have documented the few optimisations I put in place at the OS and VMWare level below. From experience I have found this results in more consistent performance across the VMs:

- http://www.stress-free.co.nz/vmware_server_20_optimisations

And here is a quick rundown on how to enable USB support on Ubuntu 8.04 with VMMWare Server 2:

- http://www.stress-free.co.nz/usb_devices_with_vmware_server_20_on_ubuntu

p.s. I have setup hypervisors running Ubuntu 8.04 32bit and 64bit without any problems.

Comment: We ended up using VMWare Player on Ubuntu 8.04 64-bit in the end; haven't had a chance to test Radu's new script, hopefully in a week or two. Thanks for the resources.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no solution found yet and do have exactly the same issue.

It starts to look like these problems are showing up when:

- Ubuntu 9.10
- 64 Bit (hw/os?)
- Vmware Server 2.0.2

My setup is 2.6.31-16-server #53-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 8 05:08:02 UTC 2009 x86_64 GNU/Linux, running on a quad core Xeon (IBM x3650).

Comment: This didn't work for me, but it seems to for others:

http://radu.cotescu.com/2009/10/30/how-to-install-vmware-server-2-0-x-on-ubuntu-9-10-karmic-koala/

Answer (score 0):

I've redesigned the script with a better patch and now VMware Server seems more stable. Please test it again. Also now I've added support for Fedora and openSUSE.